# Tensor matrix product invariant under rotation matrix

Tags: tensor-products

$\alpha$ is a tensor and its multiplication with a matrix $M\in \mathbb{R}^{3x3}$ is

$$(\alpha (M))_{ij} = \sum_{k,l} \alpha_{kl,ij} M_{kl}$$

And its multiplication is invariant under rotation, say

$$\alpha(R^T E R) = R^T \alpha(E) R \quad \forall R \in SO(3)$$

Why it is in the following form:

$$\alpha(E) = 2\mu E + \lambda tr(E) I$$

where $\mu$ and $\lambda$ are constants.

Answer (score 0):

By examining the components of 
$\alpha(R^T E R) = R^T \alpha(E) R$
one can show that $\alpha$ is *isotropic*. 
It is known that the most general isotropic tensor of fourth order is 
$$a\delta_{ij}\delta_{kl} + b\delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}+c\delta_{il}\delta_{jk}.$$
(See the proof by Fitzpatrick [here](https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336L/Fluid/node252.html).) 
It is then a straightforward exercise to show that 
$$\alpha(M) = a\mathrm{Tr}(M)\mathbb{I}+b M+c M^T.$$
If $M$ is symmetric, the result follows.